# Delete Duplicates From SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm a complete SQL noob (never actually used it before) and I need to delete duplicates from a database, which I'm posting the code for below. Duplicate rows are exactly the same except for a unique ID.

```
public class PostsDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DB_NAME = "facebookPosts.sqlite";
private static final int VERSION = 2;
private static final String TABLE_POST = "post";

public PostsDatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override 
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("create table post(_id integer primary key autoincrement, filler string, post_id integer,"
            + "application string, caption string, created_time int, description string, from_ string, fromId string,"
            + "link string, message string, name string, picture string, place string, story string, to_ string)");
}

public void deleteDuplicates(){
    getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("DELETE FROM post WHERE post._id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(post._id) FROM post GROUP BY post.post_id", null);
}
}
```

I've looked at many other threads and tried their answers, but it still doesn't work (it's probably some misunderstanding of the syntax). Thoughts?

Comment: a right bracket is missing before inverted comma

Comment: Thank you! At least my code compiles now, but it doesn't actually delete the duplicates...

Comment: Show two example records that should be detected as duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use execSQL(String sql) instead of rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)

```
public void deleteDuplicates(){
    getWritableDatabase().execSQL("delete from post where _id not in (SELECT MIN(_id ) FROM post GROUP BY post_id)");
}
```

Comment: +1. `rawQuery` only executes QUERYes (**SELECT**). ALL other SQL COMMANDS are executed through `execSQL`

Comment: Thanks guys, but I found a workaround that checks if a row is in the db before adding a row to the db.